# Eclipseのコンテンツアシストの決定キーバインドの変更

Tags: eclipse

Eclipseのコンテンツアシストで，候補を選択する際の決定キーをtabキーでできるようにしたいのですが，そのような方法はありますか? Enterキーで候補を無視して改行するようにしたいので，Enterを使いたくありません．

Answer (score 2):

@へろっぱ さんが御利用中の OS 、キーバインド設定 (Windows か、Emacs か) がないので 一旦 Windows 用で回答します。
デフォルトのキーバインドから 2 箇所変更する必要があります。

1. `Next Column` のキーバインド変更

Eclipse のメニューから `Window` => `Preferences` を開きます。
サイドメニューから `General` => `Keys` を選択しキーバインドのメニューを開きます。
Filter を入力するテキストボックスに `Next Column` を入力し、そこに出てきた `Next Column` に Enter キーを設定します。

これで一応候補が出てきた時に Enter キーで候補をスルーすることができます。
これだけだと Enter キーで改行時に改行が消えて変な挙動をしますので追加で以下も設定します。

2. `Insert Line Below Current Line` のキーバインド変更

Filter を入力するテキストボックスに `Insert Line Below` と入力し、そこに出てきた `Insert Line Below Current Line` に `Enter` を設定します。

こうすることで候補を無視しながら、今まで通り改行も挿入できるようになります。
ただ、標準で使う Enter キーを登録してしまうため、今まで当たり前にできていた操作で思わぬ弊害があるかもしれませんのでお気をつけて。